# SQL Match Multiple Queries in one Pass

Tags: mysql, opencart

I have the following MySQL table detailed below. I'm trying to select any products which appear in multiple given filter ID's.

e.g.

```
SELECT `product_id` FROM mytable WHERE (`filter_id`='100' AND `filter_id`='132');
```

I'd like to see this return 'product_id=2' but I appreciate that the above doesn't work because SQL is looking for one line which eq 100 AND 132.

I've tried playing round with UNION but that only returned products which were in filter 100 OR 132. Could someone steer me in the correct direction please?

Here is an example of my table:

```
product_id    filter_id
------------------------
1             100
2             132
2             100
3             132
3             92
4             92
```

Could someone also suggest a better title for this topic too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select m1.product_id from mytable m1 
inner join mytable m2 
on 
     (m1.`filter_id`='100' and 
      m2.`filter_id`='132' and 
      m1.product_id=m2.product_id )

Comment: Thanks Yehuda! Can you give me an example as to how I'd expand this into three matching criteria? e.g. filter=1 and filter=2 and filter=3?

Comment: No Problem, you can extend the query like this:-  select m1.product_id from mytable m1 inner join (mytable m2, mytable m3) on (m1.filter_id='100' and m2.filter_id='132' and m3.filter_id = '92' and m1.product_id=m2.product_id and m1.product_id=m3.product_id)